# Retrieving logical parent's node ID from current node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent

Need your help in **XPath** or **XSLT**.

I'm new to both of them, but right now I have to solve a case that sounds like simple at the first time but after so many tries, hard for me to solve :)

I have the following (*simplified*) XML.

First, the "***clean***" one:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <a1>
            <a11>
                <x1>111</x1>
                <x2>222</x2>
                <x3>333</x3>
            </a11>
        </a1>
    </a> 
    <b>
        <b1>
            <b11>
                <b111>
                    <x2>777</x2>
                    <x3>888</x3>
                </b111>
            </b11>
        </b1>
    </b>
</root>
```

And the second one, the same XML but with additional "**logical**" *ID numbers*. These IDs helps crosscheck the result later, they physically doesn't exist in the XML.

```
<root>
1    <a>
    1    <a1>
        1    <a11>
            1    <x1>111</x1>
            2    <x2>222</x2>
            3    <x3>333</x3>
            </a11>
        </a1>
    </a> 
2    <b>
    1    <b1>
        1    <b11>
            1    <b111>
                1    <x2>777</x2>
                2    <x3>888</x3>
                </b111>
            </b11>
        </b1>
    </b>
</root>
```

My goal is, **to retrieve the logical ID number of the current node and all it's parent, grandparent...so on (except the 'root' node) in sequence, starting from the current node**.

For example, if my current node position is at `root/a/a1/a11/x2`, then I want to produce an output similiar like this:

> Output: 2.1.1.1

where (in sequence, left to right):

```
'2' = 'x2' node
'1' = 'a11' node
'1' = 'a1' node
'1' = 'a' node
```

Right now, all I know is getting the current node ID number and it's one level parent above only, by using these XPath:

```
count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1   
count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

But I still can't figure out how to get the rest (if any) of it's parents ID number. Since the node depth level of the XML are vary, and most of time are more than 2 level depth, then I have to cover that possibility also.

I hope my question is clear.

Please, anybody have a solution? It'll be very much helpful for a beginner like me if you can give some explanation on your solution too :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ancestor-or-self` axis to enumerate all ancestors of a node like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[position() &lt; last()]">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">.</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For the node `root/a/a1/a11/x2`, this will output `2.1.1.1`.

The predicate `[position() &lt; last()]` is used to exclude the root element. `xsl:sort` is used to process the ancestors in reverse document order.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now I'm going to try your solution with my actual data. I'll be back soon with the result.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I have tested it against my actual XML data, modify your code to make some adjustments to suit my need and it worked. Thank you very much. Very appreciate it. Case close.